# External Table ERROR [08S02] Unexpected protocol character/message

Tags: netezza

When creating a flat file using a transient external table I get a strange error. `Error: Unexpected protocol character/message (State:08S02, Native Code: F)`

**Code**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 'FilePath' USING( REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC' DELIM 199 NULLVALUE ''  )
AS select * from table
```

Answer (score 1):

After researching online, [this answer helped.](http://databasebestpractices.com/netezza-error-08s02-unexpected-protocol-charactermessage/)  I ended up adding `escapeChar '\'` to the parameters and the file was successfully created.

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 'FilePath' 
           USING( REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC' DELIM 199 NULLVALUE '' escapeChar '\' )
    AS select * from table
```